# Adding multi-level menu's with Timber

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, timber

I am not familiar with Timber - in-fact this is the first time I've ever heard of it, but I'm helping a charity out who's web developer have left them in the lurch.

I've worked most things out - except getting sub-menu's working.

When items are added to the sub-menu location in Wordpress, they are appearing on the same level on the main menu.

Was wondering if someone could help me out?

Code is below for the various "twigs" - but let me know if you need the functions code as well to help out.

menu.twig:

```
    {% for item in menu %}
        <li class="{{ prefix }}__li {{ item.classes | join(' ') }}">
                <a class="{{ prefix }}__a" target="{{ item.target }}" href="{{ item.link }}"><span>{{ item.title }}</span></a>
                {% include "menu.twig" with {'menu': item.get_children} %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

header.twig

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__secondary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="header__nav nav-secondary">
                        <ul class="nav-secondary__ul">
                            {% include "menu.twig" with {
                                'menu': menu.header_secondary.items,
                                'prefix': 'nav-secondary'
                            } %}
                            <li class="nav-secondary__li nav-secondary__li--cart">
                                <a class="nav-secondary__a cart-customlocation" href="{{ cart_url }}"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__primary">
        {% block header %}
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                        <a href="/" class="header__logo">
                            <img src="{{ site.theme.link }}/dist/img/logo.jpg" alt="{{ site.name }} Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-10">
                        <nav class="header__nav nav" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="nav__ul">
                                {% include "menu.twig" with {
                                    'menu': menu.header_primary.items,
                                    'prefix': 'nav'
                                } %}
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="hamburger hamburger--spring">
                            <div class="hamburger-box">
                                <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</header>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Timber starter-theme
 * https://github.com/timber/starter-theme
 *
 * @package  WordPress
 * @subpackage  Timber
 * @since   Timber 0.1
 */

if ( ! class_exists( 'Timber' ) ) {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', function() {
        echo '<div class="error"><p>Timber not activated. Make sure you activate the plugin in <a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'plugins.php#timber' ) ) . '">' . esc_url( admin_url( 'plugins.php' ) ) . '</a></p></div>';
    });

    add_filter('template_include', function( $template ) {
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/static/no-timber.html';
    });

    return;
}

Timber::$dirname = array('views');
Timber::$autoescape = false;


/**
 * We're going to configure our theme inside of a subclass of Timber\Site
 * You can move this to its own file and include here via php's include("MySite.php")
 */
class StarterSite extends Timber\Site {
    /** Add timber support. */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'theme_supports' ) );
        add_filter( 'timber_context', array( $this, 'add_to_context' ) );
        add_filter( 'get_twig', array( $this, 'add_to_twig' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_taxonomies' ) );

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'load_scripts'] );
        parent::__construct();

        register_nav_menu('header-secondary', 'Header Secondary');
        register_nav_menu('header-primary', 'Header Primary');

        remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0); // kill woo breadcrumbs
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' , 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 ); // kill woo sorting
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' , 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 ); // kill woo # results
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', [$this, 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment']);

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
            return array(
            'width' => 400,
            'height' => 400,
            'crop' => 0,
            );
        });


        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {
            add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
        } );
    }

    /** This is where you can register custom post types. */
    public function register_post_types() {

        $name = "adoption";
        $singular = "Adoption";
        $plural = "Adoptions";

        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x("$plural", 'en'),
            'singular_name' => _x("$singular", 'en'),
            'all_items' => "All $plural",
            'add_new' => _x("Add New $singular", 'en'),
            'add_new_item' => _x("Add New $singular", 'en'),
            'edit_item' => _x("Edit $singular", 'en'),
            'new_item' => _x("New $singular", 'en'),
            'view_item' => _x("View $singular", 'en'),
            'search_items' => _x("Search $plural", 'en'),
            'not_found' => _x("No $singular found", 'en'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => _x("No $singular found in Trash", 'en'),
            'parent_item_colon' => _x("Parent $singular:", 'en'),
            'menu_name' => _x("$plural", 'en'),
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'description' => $plural,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail',
                'revisions'
            ),
            'taxonomies' => ['adoption_type'],
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 4,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-view-site',
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post'
        );

        register_post_type($name, $args);


        $name = "event";
        $singular = "Event";
        $plural = "Events";

        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x("$plural", 'en'),
            'singular_name' => _x("$singular", 'en'),
            'all_items' => "All $plural",
            'add_new' => _x("Add New $singular", 'en'),
            'add_new_item' => _x("Add New $singular", 'en'),
            'edit_item' => _x("Edit $singular", 'en'),
            'new_item' => _x("New $singular", 'en'),
            'view_item' => _x("View $singular", 'en'),
            'search_items' => _x("Search $plural", 'en'),
            'not_found' => _x("No $singular found", 'en'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => _x("No $singular found in Trash", 'en'),
            'parent_item_colon' => _x("Parent $singular:", 'en'),
            'menu_name' => _x("$plural", 'en'),
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'description' => $plural,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail',
                'revisions'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 4,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-view-site',
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post'
        );

        register_post_type($name, $args);

        if(function_exists('acf_add_options_page')) {
            acf_add_options_page([
                'page_title'    => 'Theme Content',
                'menu_title'    => 'Theme Content',
                'menu_slug'     => 'theme-content',
                'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
                'redirect'      => false
            ]);
        }

        if(function_exists('acf_add_options_page')) {
            acf_add_options_page([
                'page_title'    => 'Donation Settings',
                'menu_title'    => 'Donation Settings',
                'menu_slug'     => 'donation-settings',
                'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
                'redirect'      => false
            ]);
        }

    }
    /** This is where you can register custom taxonomies. */
    public function register_taxonomies() {

        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => 'Adoption Types',
            'singular_name'              => 'Adoption Type',
            'menu_name'                  => 'Adoption Type'
        );

        $rewrite = array(
            'slug'                       => 'adoptions',
            'with_front'                 => true,
            'hierarchical'               => false,
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'                     => $labels,
            'hierarchical'               => true,
            'public'                     => true,
            'show_ui'                    => true,
            'show_admin_column'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'show_tagcloud'              => false,
            'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'adoption_type', 'adoption', $args );

    }

    public function load_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/css/main.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script('slick-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/plugins/slick.min.js', 'jquery', false, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/main.js', ['jquery', 'slick-js'], false, true);
    }

    /** This is where you add some context
     *
     * @param string $context context['this'] Being the Twig's {{ this }}.
     */
    public function add_to_context( $context ) {

        $context['options'] = get_fields('options');

        $context['menu']['header_primary'] = new Timber\Menu('header-primary');
        $context['menu']['header_secondary'] = new Timber\Menu('header-secondary');

        $context['shop_url'] = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop' ));

        $context['site'] = $this;


        if (get_the_ID()) {
            // load page modules
            require_once('src/modules.php');
        }

        return $context;
    }

    public function theme_supports() {
        // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        /*
         * Let WordPress manage the document title.
         * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
         * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
         * provide it for us.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        /*
         * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
         *
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/
         */
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        /*
         * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
         * to output valid HTML5.
         */
        add_theme_support(
            'html5', array(
                'comment-form',
                'comment-list',
                'gallery',
                'caption',
            )
        );

        /*
         * Enable support for Post Formats.
         *
         * See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats
         */
        add_theme_support(
            'post-formats', array(
                'aside',
                'image',
                'video',
                'quote',
                'link',
                'gallery',
                'audio',
            )
        );

        add_theme_support( 'menus' );
    }

    /** This Would return 'foo bar!'.
     *
     * @param string $text being 'foo', then returned 'foo bar!'.
     */
    public function myfoo( $text ) {
        $text .= ' bar!';
        return $text;
    }

    /** This is where you can add your own functions to twig.
     *
     * @param string $twig get extension.
     */
    public function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
        $twig->addExtension( new Twig_Extension_StringLoader() );
        $twig->addFilter( new Twig_SimpleFilter( 'myfoo', array( $this, 'myfoo' ) ) );
        return $twig;
    }

    function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        ob_start();

        ?>
        <a class="cart-customlocation" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
        <?php

        $fragments['a.cart-customlocation'] = ob_get_clean();

        return $fragments;
    }

}

new StarterSite();
```

EDIT: Based on feedback received, the menu.twig code is as follows - however, not showing any menus now:

```
{% if items|default(menu.items) %}
<ul>
   {% for item in items|default(menu.items) %}
        <li class="{{ prefix }}__li {{ item.classes | join(' ') }}">
            <a class="{{ prefix }}__a" target="{{ item.target }}" href="{{ item.link }}"><span>{{ item.title }}</span></a>
            {% include "menu.twig" with {'menu': item.get_children} %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

EDIT 2: Below is header.twig as there's some more menu stuff in there...

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__secondary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="header__nav nav-secondary">
                        <ul class="nav-secondary__ul">
                            {% include "menu.twig" with {
                                'menu': menu.menu_header_secondary.items,
                                'prefix': 'nav-secondary'
                            } %}
                            <li class="nav-secondary__li nav-secondary__li--cart">
                                <a class="nav-secondary__a cart-customlocation" href="{{ cart_url }}"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__primary">
        {% block header %}
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                        <a href="/" class="header__logo">
                            <img src="{{ site.theme.link }}/dist/img/logo.jpg" alt="{{ site.name }} Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-10">
                        <nav class="header__nav nav" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="nav__ul">
                                {% include "menu.twig" with {
                                    'menu': menu.menu_header_primary.items,
                                    'prefix': 'nav'
                                } %}
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="hamburger hamburger--spring">
                            <div class="hamburger-box">
                                <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</header>
```

EDIT 3 - current config after @Gchtr input and getting the correct menus to display in the correct locations.  Still no sub-menus:

menu.twig:

```
{% set items = items|default(menu.items) %}

{% if items %}
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li class="{{ prefix }}__li {{ item.classes | join(' ') }}">
            <a class="{{ prefix }}__a" target="{{ item.target }}" href="{{ item.link }}"><span>{{ item.title }}</span></a>
            {% if item.children %}
                {% include "menu.twig" with { items: item.children } %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

header.twig:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__secondary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="header__nav nav-secondary">
                        <ul class="nav-secondary__ul">
                            {% include "menu.twig" with {
                                'menu': menu_header_secondary,
                                'prefix': 'nav-secondary'
                            } %}
                            <li class="nav-secondary__li nav-secondary__li--cart">
                                <a class="nav-secondary__a cart-customlocation" href="{{ cart_url }}"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header__primary">
        {% block header %}
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
                        <a href="/" class="header__logo">
                            <img src="{{ site.theme.link }}/dist/img/logo.jpg" alt="{{ site.name }} Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-10">
                        <nav class="header__nav nav" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="nav__ul">
                                {% include "menu.twig" with {
                                    'menu': menu_header_primary,
                                    'prefix': 'nav'
                                } %}
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="hamburger hamburger--spring">
                            <div class="hamburger-box">
                                <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</header>
```

functions.php (snippet of the Header Stuff instead of the whole lot):

```
        public function add_to_context( $context ) {

        $context['options'] = get_fields('options');

                $context['menu_header_primary']   = new Timber\Menu( 'header-primary' );
                $context['menu_header_secondary'] = new Timber\Menu( 'header-secondary') ;

        $context['shop_url'] = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop' ));

                $context['site'] = $this;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `StarterSite` class in the `add_to_context()` method, you’re adding your menus like so:

```php
$context['menu']['header_primary'] = new Timber\Menu('header-primary');
$context['menu']['header_secondary'] = new Timber\Menu('header-secondary');
```

When you now want to use access `menu.items` in your Twig, that doesn’t work, because you don’t access the nested value. It should be `menu.header_primary.items`. To simplify this, I’d change that to use separate context entries:

```php
$context['menu_header_primary']   = new Timber\Menu( 'header-primary' );
$context['menu_header_secondary'] = new Timber\Menu( 'header-secondary') ;
```

Then, for your Twig file, you’ll always need to pass a `menu` variable.

```
{% set items = items|default(menu.items) %}

{% if items %}
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li class="{{ prefix }}__li {{ item.classes | join(' ') }}">
            <a class="{{ prefix }}__a" target="{{ item.target }}" href="{{ item.link }}"><span>{{ item.title }}</span></a>
            {% if item.children %}
                {% include "menu.twig" with { items: item.children } %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

**Edit**

In your **header.twig**, you’ll need to remove the nesting from menu include as well (`menu_header_primary.items` instead of `menu.menu_header_primary.items`. Otherwise, Timber will the take the first menu it can find.

```
<nav class="header__nav nav" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav__ul">
        {% include "menu.twig" with {
            menu: menu_header_primary,
            prefix: 'nav'
        } %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: implemented, and now throwing another PHP error: `[Thu Aug 08 15:28:21.609275 2019] [php7:error] [pid 16744] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:61657] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 75513856 bytes) in /var/www/XXX/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(462) : eval()'d code on line 49` - Changed the functions.php and menu.twig to the above as per your suggestion.  Apologies if I'm being a little dense!

Comment: Okay, we seem to be running into an infinite loop. I updated the Twig code in my answer with another `items` variable. In the nested include, we pass `items` instead of `menu`, so that we can directly pass the array of child menu items. I hope this works now.

Comment: `[Fri Aug 09 10:33:06.260136 2019] [php7:error] [pid 21708] [client 110.173.229.2:54443] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73416704 bytes) in /var/www/haart/www/wp-content/mu-plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(462) : eval()'d code on line 59`

Comment: `[Fri Aug 09 10:33:07.382259 2019] [php7:error] [pid 21708] [client 110.173.229.2:54443] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73416704 bytes) in /var/www/haart/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3106`

Comment: `[Fri Aug 09 10:33:07.386648 2019] [php7:error] [pid 21708] [client 110.173.229.2:54443] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73400320 bytes) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Hey @BlackDog. I reproduced the error and fixed it by wrapping the `{% include %}` tag with an `{% if item.children %}` check. And I updated the example. I hope it works now!

Comment: Hey @Gchtr - that got the menu back without any issues.  However, still not showing any child items and the secondary menu is now showing items on the primary menu.  Any ideas on that?  Cheers, Dave

Comment: @BlackDog Did you [assign the menus properly to their menu locations](https://wordpress.org/support/article/appearance-menus-screen/#adding-your-menu-to-your-site) in the **Appearance**  → **Menus** screen?

Comment: Yeah, all menus are correct in Wordpress. The primary menu has the multi level. The secondary has only 2 items. Both locations are showing content from the primary menu.

Comment: Updated original question with header.twig as found some reference in there.

Comment: @BlackDog I updated my answer, now we’re getting there! I think the problem was with the `menu` variable that you passed to **menu.twig**.

Comment: Alright!  I've got the menus back, I'll update the code above to what is currently there.  Still no sub-menus thought.  Sincerely appreciate your perseverance with this one mate!

Comment: ignore that - CSS was the issue after that one.  It's working!  Thanks heaps for your assistance!!

Comment: @BlackDog Cool, I’m glad it’s working! You’re welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Function.php**

```
/**
     * Regsiter Nav Menus
     */
    public function theme_register_nav_menus() {
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary_menu' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'themenamehere' ),
            'secondary_menu' => esc_html__( 'Secondary Menu', 'themenamehere' ),
        ) );        
    }
```

```
/** This is where you add some context
     *
     * @param string $context context['this'] Being the Twig's {{ this }}.
     */
    public function add_to_context( $context ) {
        $context['menu']  = new Timber\Menu();
        $context['secondaryMenu']  = new Timber\Menu('secondary_menu');
        $context['site']  = $this;
        return $context;
    }
```

**Menu.twig**

```
{% if menu %}
    <ul>
        {% for item in items %}
            <li class="{{ item.classes | join(' ')}}">
                {# <a target="{{ item.target}}" href="{{ item.link}}">{{ item.title}}</a> #}
                <a target="_self" href="{{ item.link}}">{{ item.title}}</a>
                {% include "menu.twig" with{'items':item.children} %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

After that include that file inside Twig file bascically in **base.twig** file:

*For Primary Menu Code looks like:*

```
{% include "menu.twig" with{'items':menu.get_items} %}
```

*For Secondary Menu Code looks like:*

```
{% include "menu.twig" with{'items':secondaryMenu.get_items} %}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are missing `<ul></ul>` wrapper or you haven't posted the code in the entire:

```
{% if menu %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in menu %}
        <li class="{{ prefix }}__li {{ item.classes | join(' ') }}">
            <a class="{{ prefix }}__a"  target="{{ item.target }}" href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
            {% include "menu.twig" with {'items': item.children} %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I did think that, and updated to your code - but it sent the server into a downward spiral of memory usage.  PHP has a memory limit of 256M, I upped that to 2048M and it consumed it all.  That's the entire code of menu.twig.  The site wouldn't load after this change either.

Comment: Maybe I did a typo when copying your code, just simply ad `<ul>` after the `if` and '</ul>' before `endif`. Or update your code above and post it complete.

Comment: Actually, in saying that, I've just added the <ul></ul> tags into the existing code and it's managed to only display the top menu items, even if there are sub-menu items.  So, a little closer.  However, the sub-menu items do not show at all now.  Do I need to specify depth somewhere?

Comment: I guess you could solve the problem if you use `{% if items|default(menu.items) %}` for the first if clause and `{% for item in items|default(menu.items) %}` in the first for loop in the example that @kybernaut.cz posted.

Comment: @Gchtr - thanks for the input, really appreciated. - I added that as you suggested, but now the menu displays completely blank.  I've edited the original post to include the code with this in it.

Comment: @BlackDog I missed another thing and wrote a separate answer. I hope that works!

Comment: @BlackDog Yep, there is the depth setting for `Timber\Menu` https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-menu/